# Parse xml(from web service) to NSDictionary in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, post, nsdictionary

I do synchronous post request and get xml. Now I need parse and save it in NSDictionary. I tried many solutions from the web. But nothing worked for me. Here's my code:

```
//Response data object
    NSData *returnData = [[NSData alloc]init];

    NSString *param = @"{params}";

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"request=%@",param];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Send the Request
    returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];

    //Get the Result of Request
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    bool debug = YES;

    NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLFile:response];

    if (debug && response) {
        NSLog(@"Response >>>> %@", xmlDoc);
    }
```

I used this [xml reader](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary.git). Here is result which I get in nslog:

```
2016-11-28 18:04:26.970 SyncPostReq[8667:305923] Response >>>> (null)
```

Comment: `dictionaryWithFile:` is not the method you are looking for. It's wait for a string path ! Use `dictionaryWithData:` => `NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithData:response];`

Comment: @Larme, thank you, but didn't work.

Comment: Oops (bad copy/paste on my previous answer), `NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithData:returnData];` (else you should have at least a warning)

Comment: @Larme, I get it and convert my string to nsdata, didn't work.

Comment: Is `response` really XML? Can you share it?

Comment: @Larme, sorry no. Thanks for try. I found solution here http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {

    NSError *parseError;
    NSDictionary* xmlDict1 = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&parseError];

            NSDictionary *dictData = [xmlDict1 objectForKey:@"event_listing"];
            arrData = [dictData objectForKey:@"event"];


            NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:arrData
                         forKey:@"Keyupevent"];

            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"KeyalldataLoad"];
             [defaults synchronize];

            uparrData =[[defaults objectForKey:@"Keyupevent"] mutableCopy];

            [arrStoreAllEventsData addObjectsFromArray:uparrData];


            [self.tblView reloadData];
            [self loadPastEventdatafromxml];

        }] resume];
```